# Room: DAO query that removes duplicates given multiple columns as criteria

Tags: android, sqlite, dao, android-room

Assuming we are using [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) and have a [DAO](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Dao) which implements our interactions with an SQLite table. Is there a way to construct a query that can identify one or more columns that have the same value, i.e. considered duplicates, and remove them?

E.g. we have this table:

```
primKey | name | lastname | phone |
 1        foo      bar       222
 2        foo      bar       333  
 3        oof      rab       123
```

In this case, we consider `name` and `lastname` to be the criteria to determine if the row is identical. So if `name` and `lastname` is the same we want to keep only one row, as there exist duplicates. Here row 1, 2 are duplicate.

[More or less this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563289/delete-duplicates-entries-in-sqlite) but I cannot use for example `USING table`, I am getting errors. And I am also not sure how to use multiple columns as criteria.

Comment: did you consider using `Composite Primary Key`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try creating the following `Query` in your `DAO` interface:

```
@Dao
public interface MyDaoTest {

    ...

    @Query("DELETE FROM test
            WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM test GROUP BY name, lastName)")
    void deleteDuplicates();

    ...
}
```

That query, will delete all the rows in which the `name` and `lastName` are duplicated.

For example, if we have the following table, we can see that the rows with id `1`, `2` and `6` are duplicates, the same with the rows with id `3` and `4`, whereas the row with `5` has no duplicates.

[image: original table with duplicates]

This query will group the rows by `name` and `lastName`, leaving only the one with the minimum ID. By doing that, we make sure we get only one row per every set of duplicate rows (the one with the minimum ID)

```
SELECT MIN(id)
FROM test
GROUP BY name, lastName;
```

[image: result of select min]

Finally, if we delete all the the rows whose IDs are not contained in the result of that internal query, we will get rid of the duplicates.

```
DELETE
FROM test
WHERE id NOT IN
(SELECT MIN(id)
FROM test
GROUP BY name, lastName);
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Composite Primary Key*

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["name", "lastname"])
data class User(
    // you can ignore your primaryKey field
    val name: String,
    val lastname: String,
    val phone: Long
)
```

So whenever you insert a new value you can override or just ignore if `name` and `lastname` are the same.

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun insertReplace(user: User)

@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insertIgnore(user: User)
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I like the different approach. We use already the `OnConflictStrategy`. However we need to keep our primary key. In any case I was wandering if this can be done with a query or with some other built-in feature.