# How to delete duplicate values in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

```
id | name
-----------
1  | name1
2  | name2
3  | name1
4  | name2
5  | name2
6  | name2
```

I want to delete duplicate values of name when there is data like above in sqlite table
How can I do that?

I read the article below but did not understand

Thanks for reading

[Delete duplicates entries in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563289/delete-duplicates-entries-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 3):

From the answer of the question you linked, you can do this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(id) FROM table_name GROUP BY name)
```

This will only leave the min id for each name with duplicates.